# Looking for a specific Java application for performance testing

Tags: java, monitoring

For purely experimental reasons, and to learn about monitoring applications, looking for something with the following criteria:

- written in Java
- web application, runnable in a web container (tomcat). not using EJBs/JMS.
- open-source
- somewhat resource-intensive
- using MySQL for DB
- makes good use of logs (that is, writes to logs often and descriptively)
- works fairly simple in EC2, i guess - what kinds of problem could be there? maybe usage of many ports?

The intention here is to be able to send it http query (or soap) requests and be able to significantly load it. Looking for some fresh ideas.
Thanks!

Comment: Uh, a web application? What kind of applications would you like to test for performance then?

Comment: "somewhat resource-intensive"?

Comment: He wants to learn about performance testing by taking an existing app and testing it.

Comment: CPU intensive, or I/O intensive would be more precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppFuse is a Java web stack that meets all of these requirements (I don't know what you mean by resource-intensive, but you could always add your own functionality that is CPU-intensive, or I/O intensive, or whatever - or just put load on it).

Here is a [link](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart) to the quick start guide.

Actually, since it supports multiple web frameworks (Spring MVC, Struts, Wicket, etc), one use case for your performance testing could involve testing with each one to compare different types of functionality.